# Hashing Function for HashMap

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, computer-science, immutable.js

I'm working on a library that implements a lot of data structures, and I'm making it mostly for learning purposes because I want to learn more about data structures. I'm implementing HashMap at the moment and I'm running into a bit of trouble trying to implement an efficient, collision preventive hashing function. I'm no expert in data structures nor hashing algorithms so please don't be harsh.

Currently my hashing function works, you pass it a string and it returns a hash. This hash is the index that a value will be stored in an array. A sample hash that can be `return`ed looks like this `695488530`. That value gets passed as an index and stores a value `this.table[695488530] = value`. However the index is really large and because of that when I try to log out a value in my tests for `HashMap` the test just hangs and hangs, even in the browser I tried to log out it out and it crashes chrome(lol). Because its trying to log something out like:

```js
[
 undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 
 undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, undefined, 
 undefined, undefined, ... 
 After many many values when it reaches index 695488530 -> 'someValue
]
```

Eventually I waited long enough when one of my `Ava` tests tried to log out the values and it returned the following error:

```js
FATAL ERROR: invalid table size Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

<--- Last few GCs --->

    2088 ms: Scavenge 26.7 (59.0) -> 19.8 (60.0) MB, 3.7 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
    2891 ms: Scavenge 39.5 (64.0) -> 26.7 (65.0) MB, 7.6 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
    3351 ms: Scavenge 43.3 (67.0) -> 31.9 (69.0) MB, 36.6 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
    3752 ms: Scavenge 48.2 (72.0) -> 36.9 (74.0) MB, 30.5 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
    4120 ms: Scavenge 52.0 (76.0) -> 40.7 (79.0) MB, 26.6 / 0 ms [allocation failure].
```

If your wondering what hashing algorithm I am using it is crc32:

```js
function makeCRCTable () {
  var c;
  var crcTable = [];
  for(var n =0; n < 256; n++){
    c = n;
    for(var k =0; k < 8; k++){
      c = ((c&1) ? (0xEDB88320 ^ (c >>> 1)) : (c >>> 1));
    }
    crcTable[n] = c;
  }
  return crcTable;
}

function crc32 (str) {
  var crcTable = makeCRCTable();
  var crc = 0 ^ (-1);

  for (var i = 0; i < str.length; i++ ) {
    crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ crcTable[(crc ^ str.charCodeAt(i)) & 0xFF];
  }

  return (crc ^ (-1)) >>> 0;
}
```

So, that is my dilemma. I need help finding a hashing function that is resource efficient and while preventing collisions. I know that the [immutable](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js) library for persistent immutable data structures uses an extremely efficient hashing function and I would like to leverage that however I'm not exactly sure what algorithm it uses nor which parts it is from this [file](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/blob/e34bb37acd32518674f3029e894ea1e29400ec45/src/Hash.js). If anyone from the immutable, or computer science community could help me out that would be fantastic.

Comment: Could you use multiple tables? Create a new one when the old one reaches a certain size? (Sorry, I don't know much about hashing specifically.)

Comment: You do not need to create a new crc table every time you want to calculate a checksum. Just create it once during startup and re-use the same table. Also, instantiating an explicitly sized array will be faster (`new Array(256)` instead of `[]`) when generating the table. Lastly, you will run into problems with non-ASCII characters, since `charCodeAt()` will return a larger value. In that case you will need to split the character into its respective bytes.